# Удалить файл с помощью php

Tags: php, backend, удаление

Есть папка с картинками, надо удалить определённую картинку. Но выбивает ошибку: **Permission denied in**.
Вот код:

```
    require_once "connect.php";
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    unlink('uploads/'.$_POST['name']); 
    $query ="DELETE FROM `pictures` WHERE `Id` = '$id'";
    mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    header('Location: panel.php');
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У папки, из который Вы пытаетесь удалить файл, должны быть выставлены такие же группа и владелец, как и у исполняемого процесса PHP.

То есть если у Вас PHP запущен под `www-data` (по умолчанию), то и папка должна быть с группой `www-data`. Также на чтение и запись из папки нужно выставить права 755.

Comment: никогда не надо 777 ставить

Comment: А как можно узнать и поменять группу(извините за глупый вопрос)?